# Show XML data when a table row is active

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an XML data sheet. I am currently using ajax to pull data from it to create specific tabs and build a table of data. What I'm stuck on is when a row of data is selected, details are meant to show in an adjacent set of divs, much like this:

[image: What I want]

data is omitted for anonymity.
Currently this process uses Spry, I want to recreate it using jQuery.

Below if my jQuery

```
$jq.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: url,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: build,
  error: error
});

//function to create the tabs
function build(xmlData) {
  var locations = []; //create blank array to store locations
    //loop to go over every event and find locations
    $jq(xmlData).find("event").each(function (){
      var $jqLocation = $jq(this).find("location").text();
      //if location does not already exist, add to array
      if (jQuery.inArray($jqLocation, locations) == -1 ) {
        locations.push($jqLocation);
      } 
      //case statement to determine number of events
      switch ($jqLocation) {
        case 'Denver':
          denverNum += 1;
          break;
        case 'Elko, NV':
          elkoNum += 1;
          break;
        case 'Saskatoon, SK':
          saskNum += 1;
          break; 
        case 'Montreal':
          montrealNum += 1;
          break;
        case 'Vancouver, BC':
          vancouverNum += 1;
          break;
        case 'Toronto, ON':
          torontoNum += 1;
          break;
        case 'Remote Training':
          remoteNum += 1;
          break;
        case 'Gillette, WY':
          gilletteNum += 1;
          break;
      }
    })

  //iterates through the array to create the tabs if the location is present
  locations.forEach(function(place){
    switch (place) {
      case 'Denver':
        $jq('<li role="presentation" id="remoteTab"><a href="#denver" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Denver, CO</a></li>').appendTo('#tabList');
        break;
      case 'Elko, NV':
        $jq('<li role="presentation" id="remoteTab"><a href="#elko" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Elko, NV</a></li>').appendTo('#tabList');
        //iterates through XML data to find Elko events and builds the table
        $jq("event", xmlData).each(function(){
          var eventLocation = $jq(this).find('location').text();
          if (eventLocation.localeCompare('Elko, NV') == 0) {
            var date = $jq(this).find("date").text();
            var course = $jq(this).find("course").text();
            var duration = $jq(this).find("duration").text();
            var presenter = $jq(this).find("presenter").text();
            var details = $jq(this).find("details").text();
            var output = '<tr>';
            output += '<td>'+date+'</td>';
            output += '<td>'+course+'</td>';
            output += '<td>'+duration+' days</td>';
            output += '</tr>';
            $jq('#elkoTable').append(output);
            output = '<strong>';
            output += presenter;
            output += '</strong>';
            $jq('#elkoPresenter').append(output);
            output = '<strong>'+date+'</strong>';
            $jq('#elkoDate').append(output);
          };
        });
        //jquery for making rows active upon click
        $jq('#elkoTable tr').click(function() {
          $jq('tr').removeClass();
           $jq(this).addClass('active');
```

Here is the HTML it appends to

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="elkoTable">
                <tr>
                  <th width="150" spry:sort="date">Date (yr-mth-day)</th>
                  <th align="left" spry:sort="course">Course</th>
                  <th width="100" spry:sort="duration">Duration</th>
                </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" tabindex="0">Details</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <!-- <div id="Specials_Detail_DIV2" spry:detailregion="Vulcan_elko"> -->
            <div id="Specials_Detail_DIV2">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                  <p>
                    <span class="small">Course:</span>
                    <br>
                    <!-- <strong>{course}</strong> -->
                  </p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still struggling with the solution to this, I found a wacky way around it.
I created a variable and basically created all the divs in the variable and appended it to the html. Upon clicking the table row, it grabs the row ID and finds the correct div that matches the ID + 'Details'.

```
var detailsPane = '<div class="panel panel-default" id="'+id+'Details" style="display: none;"><div class="panel-heading" tabindex="0">Details</div><div class="panel-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-9"><p><span class="small">Course:</span><br><strong>'+course+'</strong></p></div><div class="col-xs-3"><a href="https://maptek.secure.force.com/training/TrainingWorkshopRegister?WSId=' + id +'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Register Now</a></div></div>';
            detailsPane += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-3"><p><span class="small">Date:</span><br><strong>'+date+'</strong> </p> </div><div class="col-xs-3"><p><span class="small">Duration:</span><br><strong>'+duration+' Days</strong></p></div><div class="col-xs-6"><p><span class="small">Presenter:</span><br><strong>'+presenter+'</strong></p></div></div>';
            detailsPane += '<hr>';
            detailsPane += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div><div style="text-align:right"><strong>'+isFull+'</strong> </div></div>'+details;
            detailsPane += '<hr>';
            detailsPane += '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><h4>Provided with each course</h4><ul><li>Laptop Software/license</li><li>Training manual</li><li>Writing materials</li><li>Lunch</li><li>Coffee break refreshments</li></ul></div><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><h4>Facility Rentals </h4><p>Training facilities and laptops can be reserved .</p><p>For more information contact <a href=">email</a> or call <a href="tel">+1 9</a></p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
            $jq('#details').append(detailsPane);
```

this if followed by the code to make it show

```
var id = $jq(this).attr('id');
$jq('#'+id+'Details').show();
```